# Scroll bug in Chrome on Windows with Swipe-script

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am using this swipe script from iDangero but I have a small, everywhere it works perfect but only Chrome on windows is giving me a hard time. I already stated the issue at the owner of the script but he can't find a solution for the script at this point, maybe somebody here can help me.

**Issue at GitHub:**
https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/825

**Script URL:**
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

**URL:**
http://testjevorm.nl/magazine

**The Problem:**
As soon as you go to the website you have the possibility to navigate to the next slide in two ways:

1. Click on the "UITGELICHT ARTIKEL"-block on the left.
2. Click on the arrow on the right

When you click on the block on the left it's not possible to scroll up and down on the next page (the scroll is somehow not working/disabled). The weird thing is that it "activates" when you click on the arrow in the menu right or hover over the social media icons on a page.

**To show the issue I made a small video:**
http://youtu.be/T8Bnz2fsvhU
(Yes, it's windows XP but the problem is also there in Windows Vista and Windows 7)

Part of the solution:
I found out that it has to do with the css I added myself:

```
body {width:100%; height:100%;}
html {width:100%; height:100%;}
```

When I remove this, the problem is solved but then all the pages have the same height as the longest page in the serie.

Answer (score 0):

just tried what you told me to do on my Mac. It works fine on my Mac, but that's not what you said that didn't work, so I tried it on a Windows 8 Laptop.

Well... it works perfectly fine for me, with Chrome 35 on Windows 8. I assume that you either resolved the issue, or that there's something wrong with your Windows XP setup on mac.

**Note:** I highly doubt that there is a issue on your website, which will only "show up" in Windows 7 or below, as Windows has always been pretty much downwards compatible (and I'm sure they haven't changed anything about the scroll behavior).

**Note 2:** If you're still having the issue, it might be chrome on Windows XP. But as you want it to work on that as well (or your companies policy states so), then try this:

In your CSS, simply add `overflow-x: scroll` to your body.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but adding the overflow doesn't help.. :( the problem also occurs on vista and windows 7. (not only through my mac but also in windows computers). And i have tested it on many different devices, the person who build the script also have the issue

Comment: I gave it a +1 hoping that someone who has another idea could help. I don't encounter the issue, but it might actually be a Chrome bug. Tried it in different browsers?

Comment: Every other browser is not giving any problems, IE, Firefox, Safari and Opera are all okay, both on mac and windows computers.

Comment: Then it really seems like theres a Bug in Chrome. Are you running the latest version of Chrome on XP?